# How Add a legend to Core Plot in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-plot

How can I add Legends in Core Plot framework?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no Legend class yet. You can fake it using an image sometimes, but it is not in Core Plot yet. [Check drewmcco Comment](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=90)
>
> Legends have not yet been implemented in Core Plot. You're more than welcome to contribute an implementation of them to the framework.
>
> In the meantime, you could construct a custom UIView with UILabels and colored lines to act as the legend for the graph, then add it as a sibling to the graph (not a subview, or it will not be rendered properly) and order it to show above the graph.
> [Check Brad Larson Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411108/core-data-line-labels)

Comment: will you please explain me more about how to Add view as sibling to coreplot graph

Comment: Can't you add an image as a subview of the graph view?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actualy I am newer to coreplot and I am still not much clear with the flow of coreplot.so will you guide me more

Comment: @Prerak: I have not gone to much in coreplot, but i suggest some stuff; `CPXYGraph* graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: frame];` can't you say `[graph addSubView:Image];`

Comment: Instead of adding a sublayer to the Core Plot graph, you could add a CPAnnotation to your graph. Depending on the type of annotation you want, you can anchor it to view (~screen) coordinates or plot coordinates. An annotation uses a CPLayer, which is a subclass of CALayer, to actually display the annotation. You can create a CPLayer and add your image as the layer "contents".

Answer (score 26):

Update: CorePlot 0.4 has the class CPTLegend:

```
_graph.legend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:_graph];
_graph.legend.textStyle = x.titleTextStyle;
_graph.legend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor darkGrayColor]];
_graph.legend.borderLineStyle = x.axisLineStyle;
_graph.legend.cornerRadius = 5.0;
_graph.legend.swatchSize = CGSizeMake(25.0, 25.0);
_graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
_graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0, 12.0);
```

See CorePlot_0.4/Source/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/SimpleScatterPlot.m.