# iOS Core plot pie chart How to draw the legend like a table

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Add a legend to Core Plot in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740785/how-add-a-legend-to-core-plot-in-iphone-sdk)

Can I draw the legend of pie chart like a table that have rows and colums with separate line between rows?